# Database Creation in android

Tags: android

I am creating a table which works on the simulator but not on the device. I get this error message:

```
Failure 1 (near "(": syntax error) on 0x2d69a8 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE request(requestidINTEGER PRIMARY KEY,longitudefromDECIMAL(10,5),lattitudefromDECIMAL(10,5),phoneINTEGER)
```

I am creating the table like this:

```
 String CREATE_REQUEST_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_REQUEST + "(" 
                    + KEY_REQUESTID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
                    + KEY_LONGITUDEFROM + "DECIMAL(10,5)," 
                    + KEY_LATTITUDEFROM + "DECIMAL(10,5)," 
                    + KEY_TO + "TEXT," 
                    + KEY_DEPARTURETIME + "TIME," 
                    + KEY_ARRIVALTIME + "TIME," 
                    + KEY_DESCRIPTION + "TEXT," 
                    + KEY_PHONE + "INTEGER" + ")"; 
            db.execSQL(CREATE_REQUEST_TABLE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with space between your id and "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"

Like;

```
    KEY_REQUESTID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have spaces in your request. Add space before and after key:

```
String CREATE_REQUEST_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_REQUEST + " (" 
                + KEY_REQUESTID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " 
                + KEY_LONGITUDEFROM + " DECIMAL(10,5), " 
                + KEY_LATTITUDEFROM + " DECIMAL(10,5), " 
                + KEY_TO + " TEXT, " 
                + KEY_DEPARTURETIME + " TIME, " 
                + KEY_ARRIVALTIME + " TIME, " 
                + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, " 
                + KEY_PHONE + " INTEGER" + ")";
```

Comment: thank you that was it but i was wondering why on the emulator it was working fine when i tried it on the device it crashes.. but now everything is working

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you can see in the error message, `KEY_REQUESTID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"` turns into `requestidINTEGER PRIMARY` which is not `requestid INTEGER PRIMARY`. Basically, there is no space between the column name and the column type which makes them look (to SQLite) as a single token.